# Class isn't outputting arguments/doing anything? (Python)

Tags: python, class, oop, object

```
class Fridge:
    def __init__ (self, food, quantity):
        self.food=food
        self.quantity=quantity
    def UserEntry(self):
        if input=="milk":
            print("you got milk!")
        else:
            print ("What do you want?")
    def DisplayFridge(self):
        print("Fridge_item#1 :" , self.food, "Quantity:" , self.quantity)
```

When I attempt to instantiate the class, such as:

```
test= Fridge
```

and as soon as a I open the parenthesis in order to instantiate the class such as follows:

```
test = Fridge (
```

I am presented with the arguments that were passed to the class constructor/initialization method. (i.e. food and quantity).

With that in mind then....I am at a bit of a loss as to why I am not getting any output. nor, am I being asked for input, etc.

Comment: Please write your full code. If you define the instance like `test = Fridge('spam', 42)`, how do you try to print the data. And what do you think `if input == "milk"` does? Hint: You're comparing a function object with a string here.

Comment: Where do you think you will be asked for input? Where are you calling the display method so that you get output?

Comment: I have written my full code :\

Comment: Well then you haven't called any code that does input or output, so it's hard to understand why you think there should be some.

Comment: I thought input asked for a value from the user

Comment: Firstly, that's `input()`; secondly, *you haven't called the UserEntry method*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting any input this way, you should try :

```
class Fridge:
    def __init__ (self, food, quantity):
        self.food=food
        self.quantity=quantity
    def UserEntry(self):
        var = raw_input("Please enter something: ")
        if var=="milk":
            print("you got milk!")
        else:
            print ("What do you want?")
    def DisplayFridge(self):
        print("Fridge_item#1 :" , self.food, "Quantity:" , self.quantity)
```

But there is serious lack of logic in your code :

- Why UserEntry is never used ?
- How do you use Fridge ?
- You userEntry method will never change your self.food variable.

Comment: Logic didn't really come into it tbh. This is the very first time Ive used OOP, I am teaching myself, and I was more concerned about getting the technique, understanding the various parts of OOP, terminology, how to call them etc etc

Comment: You must construct your code step by step. Here, there is parts without any use. You want that UserEntry do something. Why not first test if you can get an input from user in a simple Python script and not in a method class ?

Comment: Thats the irritating thing. I had gotten an input from a user before, and even did parameter checking etc! So don't know why it didn't work out this time :o

Comment: Because you are comparing `input`, a function, to `"milk"`, a string. What you want is to compare `input()`, a string enter by the user, to "milk", a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making an instance, you type

```
test = Fridge(
```

And then it doesn't show you "the arguments that were passed to the class constructor/initialization method", but it shows you **what you have to pass in order to make an instance**.

E.g.

```
test = Fridge("milk", 10)
```

And now it holds 10 milks. Try

```
test.UserEntry()
test.DisplayFridge()
```

Comment: Which raises another point of confusion for me.

What exactly is the difference between an instance and an object?

I thought of it as, an instance=singular, object=plural but, something that tells me that is a gross over-simplification that also is most likely wrong..... :(

Oh, and objects have methods whereas an instance does not......?

Comment: "Object" is a very generic term, but usually it is meant to be more or less the same as "instance". A class is the definition of what a Fridge is, and you can make many instances (fridges) using that definition.

Comment: Each instance has its own data (the self.food and self.quantity of instance a is separate from those of instance b), but you can call methods on them and they just call the ones defined on the class (but each gets its own "self" parameter).